# Format of Retry-After Header?

Tags: dropbox-api

In Dropbox's [Core API best practices](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/bestpractices) there is a statement:

> *"Apps that hit the rate limits will receive a 503 error which uses the Retry-After header to indicate exactly when it's okay to start making requests again."*

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764075/retry-after-http-response-header-does-it-affect-anything/23863426#23863426) references the `Retry-After` [protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37) which allows for two formats:

> Retry-After: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
>    Retry-After: 120

Does anyone know which format Dropbox uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the latter, where the value is the number of seconds the app should wait before trying again.