# htaccess how use %{TIME_DAY} in header set retry-after %{TIME_DAY}+1

Tags: .htaccess, header

I need to use htaccess variables like `%{TIME_DAY}` in header set and even more if possible add 1 day to it, like:

```
header set retry-after: %{TIME_DAY}+1
```

second q I searched the web for `%{TIME_MON}` which would return like jan , sep.. is there a code for it ? If not how can I make variables in htaccess which translates 01 to Jan or 12 to Dec and so on ..

This is what finally I need , but not hard coded. It will say retry tomorrow, so if today is 19 Dec 2016 the header will be set like :

```
Header set Retry-After: Tue, 20 Dec 2016 02:59:59 GMT
```

Answer (score -1):

After reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23863426/1992669) and the [`Retry-After` specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37), the easiest solution in your case is to use the "delta-seconds" version, not the "HTTP-date" version:

```
header set Retry-After 86400
```

Where 86400 seconds is one day.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong but it is not the answer to our need . first we needed to learn how to work with variables in that area .. second , if is hard coded ammount of time, we need on every hours when there is a visit the header to be set at an exact hour 02:59:59 GMT on tomorrow . but yours sets not on that exact hour, but sets after 24 hours, if it's 06AM it sets to 06AM tomorrow end if it's 11PM it set's 11PM tomorrow. As told we need an exact hour in tomorrow ..